# Tracking Facebook Business Page via Google Analytics

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

The problem:
I am not seeing any information in Google Analytics account for facebook page.

What I have done so far:
-On facebook, added Google analytics tracking code to HTML app
-In google analytics account added facebook page

What are the correct steps to track my facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple, you can't track your Facebook Page with Google Analytics.